# How is memcached updated?

Tags: caching, memcached

I have never used memcached before and I am confused on the following basic question.
Memcached is a cache right? And I assume we cache data from a DB for faster access. So when the DB is updated who is responsible to update the cache? Our code is does memcached "understand" when the DB has been updated?

Comment: Nope, _your application_ is responsible for invalidating the cache when your application updates something, or to not care whether data is stale. Choose the time cache can live carefully. And it's true what they say: _"There are only two hard problems in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things."_

Comment: @Wrikken:So the idea is that the code that eventually does `UPDATE table` also updates the cache?

Answer (score 3):

> Memcached is a cache right? And I assume we cache data from a DB for
>   faster access

Yes it is a cache, but you have to understand that a cache speed up the access when you are often accessing same data. If you access thousand times data/objects which are always different each other a cache doesn't help.

To answer your question:

> So when the DB is updated who is responsible to update the cache?

Always you but you don't have to worry about if you are doing the right thing.

> Our code is does memcached "understand" when the DB has been updated?

memcached doesn't know about your database. (actually the client doesn't know even about servers..) So when you use an object of your database you should check if is present in cache, if not you put in cache otherwise you are fine.. that is all. When the moment comes memcache will free the memory used by old data, or you can tell memcached to free data after a time you choose(read the API for details).

Answer (score 1):

You are responsible to update the cache (or some plugin).

What happens is that the query is compressed to some key features and these are hashed. This is tested against the cache. If the value is in the cache, the data is returned directly from cache. Otherwise the query is performed, stored in cache and returned to the user.

In pseudo code:

```
key = query_key(your_sql_query)
if key in cache:
  return cache.get(key)
else:
 results = execute(your_sql_query)
 cache.set(key, results, time_to_live)
 return results.
```

The cache is cleared once in a while, you can give a time to live to a key, then your cached results are refreshed.

This is the most simple model, but can cause some inconsistencies.

Comment: Concerning your pseudocode.This is to populate the cache initially. So  how do you determine if the cache is to be updated?

Comment: That is more complex. If you have a user object in a simple rest api. You can do for example a key looks like: <table>-<id>. If you update a value from table users with id 59, you reset the cache key users-59.

But when queries are variable you can keep a list of key names, which depend on a certain row in a certain table and refresh all those. The point is in naming them correctly so you can update them when needed. You need to devise some function for that.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy is that if your code is also the only app that updates data, then your code can also refresh memcached as a second step after it has updated the database. Or at least evict the stale data from memcached, so the next time an app wants to read it, it will be forced to re-query the current data from the database and restore that latest data to memcached.

Another strategy is to store data in memcached with an expiration time, so memcached automatically purges that data element after a certain time. You pick the expiration time, based on your knowledge of how frequently the data might be updated, and how tolerant your app is of reading stale data.

So ultimately, you are the one responsible for putting data into memcached. Only you know what data is worth storing in the cache, what format you want to store it in, how frequently you expect to query it, and when to refresh it. You make this judgment on a case-by-case basis, because you know better than any automatic system the likely behavior of your data and your app.